# How to count the occurence of a column which is the result of a concatenation of a string and integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, concatenation, find-occurrences

The data in my table looks like this:

```
AUDTORG | SEQUENCENO | LINE | REFERENCE | AMOUNT | 
--------------------------------------------------
ADX     | 1          | 422  | Wire1     | 10     | 
ADX     | 2          | 385  | Wire2     | 10     | 
ADX     | 2          | 335  | Wire25    | 10     | 
ADX     | 2          | 335  | Transfer  | 10     | 
BMD     | 1          | 555  | Wire4     | 10     |
```

I have to:
1. concatenate: AUDTORG and SEQUENCENO
2. Count the occurence of the concatenated field NewID.

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
AUDTORG | SEQUENCENO | LINE | REFERENCE | AMOUNT | NewID  | Occurence |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ADX     | 1          | 422  | Wire1     | 10     | ADX1   | 1         |
ADX     | 2          | 385  | Wire2     | 10     | ADX2   | 3         |
ADX     | 2          | 335  | Wire25    | 10     | ADX2   | 3         |
ADX     | 2          | 335  | Transfer  | 10     | ADX2   | 3         |
BMD     | 1          | 555  | Wire4     | 10     | BMD1   | 1         |
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
SELECT *, BKENTD.AUDTORG + CAST(BKENTD.SEQUENCENO AS varchar) as NewID,
count(BKENTD.AUDTORG + CAST(BKENTD.SEQUENCENO AS varchar)) as Occurence
FROM ADXDAT.dbo.BKENTD
```

All the rows must remain.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: . . Then my answer will work.

Comment: I just tried it, I got a msg: "The multi-part identifier “BKENTD.AUDTORG” could not be bound". Not sure if that's relevant but the query is entered into the Command Text in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using window functions:

```
SELECT b.*,
      (b.AUDTORG + CAST(b.SEQUENCENO AS varchar(255)) )as NewID,
      count(*) over (partition by b.AUDTORG + CAST(b.SEQUENCENO AS varchar(255)) ) as Occurence
FROM ADXDAT.dbo.BKENTD b;
```

The `over` clause is used by window function.  In this case, it counts everything in a group.  The group is defined by the `partition by` clause.  So, it counts everything with the same value of the new id.

Comment: Oops, I missed one of the table aliases I replaced.

Answer (score 1):

All rows must remain makes for the need for a subquery.  This will obtain counts:

```
select BKENTD.AUDTORG + CAST(BKENTD.SEQUENCENO AS varchar) as NewID, count(*) Occurence
FROM ADXDAT.dbo.BKENTD
group by BKENTD.AUDTORG + CAST(BKENTD.SEQUENCENO AS varchar)
```

You now have the NewID and count for each.  Join it back to your first statement and refer to it as a standard column (select * is now select a.* so you don't get the b.newID field):

```
SELECT a.*, BKENTD.AUDTORG + CAST(BKENTD.SEQUENCENO AS varchar) as NewID, Occurence
FROM ADXDAT.dbo.BKENTD a
inner join 
(select BKENTD.AUDTORG + CAST(BKENTD.SEQUENCENO AS varchar) as NewID, count(*) Occurence
FROM ADXDAT.dbo.BKENTD
group by BKENTD.AUDTORG + CAST(BKENTD.SEQUENCENO AS varchar)) b
on a.NewID = b.NewID
```

Comment: how do I "join it back to my first statement and refer to it as ... "? I'm not familiar with subqueries, thanks!!

Comment: @seva - I've done it for you, the second select statement there has the join to the subquery done.  I showed you the logic breakdown so you can understand it instead of just the answer :)

Comment: I'm having a error msg: Incorrect  synthax near the keyword 'FROM'. Not sure if that makes a difference, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and the query is entered in the "Command Text" in Excel through an ODBC Connection.

Comment: stupid error on my part...the subquery says from from instead of just from.  Corrected, try again.  ODBC through excel doesn't make much of a difference in syntax.

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work, got a msg: Invalid column name 'NewId'. Thank you for your time, the solution proposed by @Gordon Linoff did work.  However, I would have liked to understand the logic behind the subquery.